# High-pitch sound coming from my macbook pro when I move a wired mouse

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a Macbook Pro Retina and when I move my wired mouse (mionix Naos, but same with others) there is a high pitch sound coming from my mac.

It does not make any sound if I don't move the mouse, or if I the integrated trackpack.

The sound comes from the mac. If I use headphones the sound does not come from it, but form the mac.

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same thing with my Macbook Pro 15" Retina (Mid 2014) using both the Logitech G Pro and older G500. However, I noticed that changing the polling rate for the mouse from 1000 to 250 makes the sound very hard to hear, though the higher polling rates of 500 and 1000 makes the sound more audible. Happens with either USB input and even if both mice are plugged in at the same time. Unplugging the power adapter does not make any real difference.

Comment: @mortenandersen  I changed the polling rate to 200hz and the sound is no more. Nice finding. Would like to create an answer so that I can mark this as resolved?

Comment: yes sure. It is done and happy it helped you out :)

Comment: I coped with a similar behaviour. I use Macbook pro 2015 MJLQ2 from which sometimes I hear noise (like the fan operates strongly I think) while my Roccat lua plugged into. I also see this problem whenever my MBP is under heavy processing as if it runs Java ( such as infinite loop, overload java heap space,..)

Comment: I am having the same issue on my 2018 Macbook Pro. I am using a newer Logitech MX518 and there is a very high pitched squeal coming from the mainboard when I move the mouse. SUPER annoying. Modifying the polling rate doesn't make a significant enough difference for me, and the consequences in the sensitivity aren't worth it. I guess the only way to avoid this is to get a different mouse? I tried a ferrite bead on the USB cord with no success ... but I have no idea what I am doing there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm experiencing the exact same thing with my Macbook Pro 15" Retina (Mid 2014) using both the Logitech G Pro and older G500.

However, I noticed that **changing the polling rate** for the mouse from 1000 to 250 makes the sound very hard to hear, though the higher polling rates of 500 and 1000 makes the sound more audible. Happens with either USB input and even if both mice are plugged in at the same time. Unplugging the power adapter does not make any real difference.

Comment: Confirmed on Macbook Pro 2019 BigSur 11.2 using Razer Naga Pro. Changing polling rate from 1000Hz to 125Hz makes the noise go away when connecting via the USB dongle. When using the mouse in bluetooth there is no noise as well but the polling rate is probably super low on bluetooth.

Comment: How do you change the polling rate? | Razer Deathadder Elite here, MacBook Pro 2019, Big Sur 11.2.2

Comment: I used the Logitech Gaming Software, maybe there's something similar for Razer mice specifically?

Answer (score 2):

Since today, I noticed same behavior with my MacBook Pro Retina 15" (Early 2013) using a USB mouse (Roccat Kone XTD). The sound seems to come right from below the area around V key. Looking at the teardown images, right below on the logic board is an inductor and a Texas Instruments TPS51980 chip (power controller?), which could produce the noise.

I found out that when I unplug the PSU, the buzzing seems to be quieter (but still a bit hearable).

Answer (score 2):

It might be the grounding problem. In my case, I use a 3rd party usb adaptor. The noise goes away immediately when I unplug the power from it.

Source: https://duc.avid.com/showthread.php?t=155579

Answer (score 1):

This has to be one of the strangest things I have ever heard happening. And I've been supporting Macs since the IIci was top of the line. That said, unless someone else has another Idea I would make a Genius appointment take it into an Apple store to have them have a look.

A couple of things to check. Does the noise happen with the mouse plugged into any port? Does it happen with a wireless (with a dongle) or Bluetooth mouse? Where exactly is the noise coming from? one or more speakers, or another part of the Mac? Take the answers to those (that you can determine) to the Apple store.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a grounding problem. I had the same issue and it went away when I unplugged the computer from the charger. My charger is plugged into a surge+battery protector.
I unplugged my MBP from the power source and let the battery waste a bit and then plugged the power source back in and it goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the sound comes from around the V key.
I have 15" 2014 MBP.
I have a Corsair RGB mouse.
The sound is faint, but the sound happens in conjunction with the exact movement.
It continues even on battery or using mouse with a hub.
I did accidentally get my charger caught in a recliner and it bent one of the pins in the connector.

The sound goes away the more the mouse is moved. Once idle for at least 10 seconds, the sound becomes louder.

Either USB port it will happen.